# Python fast way to check N points are in the same "area"

Tags: python, math

I have a clicking applicaiton on a phone.

I want to sample last N points so it won't click the same "place" over and over again.

I guess it should be kind of this:

[image]

This I want to avoid.
I guess the circlue center should be the center of all points ?
How to determind the radius ?

I think calculation of the last N dots can be used to calculte the "new" N dots once a new click is done, to reduce performance.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: What does the phone have to do with it? How are you running Python on your phone? I'm not aware of any major vendors that support Python out of the box.

Comment: "How to determine the radius?"—How should we know? It depends on your requirements.

Comment: "I want to sample last N points so it won't click the same "place" over and over again… I think calculation of the last N dots can be used to calculte the "new" N dots once a new click is done, to reduce performance"—what does that mean? What is "sampling" in this case? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
    def clicking_loop_protection(self, x, y, methods):
        '''
        :param x:
        :param y:
        :param method: 'xpath'/'point' it can be both
        :return:
        '''

        def centroid(points):
            _len = len(points)

            x_coords = [p[0] for p in points]
            y_coords = [p[1] for p in points]

            centroid_x = sum(x_coords) / _len
            centroid_y = sum(y_coords) / _len
            return centroid_x, centroid_y

        def calculate_points_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
            dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
            return dist

        point_res = True

        if 'point' in methods:
            # add current point
            _point = (x, y)
            try:
                self.points_history[self.points_history_index] = _point
            except IndexError:
                self.points_history.append(_point)

            if len(self.points_history) == self.points_history_length:
                centroid_point_x, centroid_point_y = centroid(self.points_history)
                radius = self.displayWidth/10

                for point in self.points_history:
                    # distance from centroid should be less than radius (to fail the test)
                    distance = calculate_points_distance(centroid_point_x, centroid_point_y, point[0], point[1])
                    if distance > radius:
                        point_res = True  # pass test !
                        break
                    else:
                        point_res = False

            self.points_history_index += 1
            self.points_history_index %= self.points_history_length

        return xpath_res and point_res
```